# 2x excel cells, if one of the cells is 0 I need the formula to show zero, if both cells have a positive value then I need this to be added together

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Cell `45` is cells `H42:H43` added together

However I want cell `45` (`£1516.56`) to show `£0` if there is no value (`£0`) in cell `C42, however is there is a value in 'C42' then I need this added to 'C43' is there a formula to do this?

[image: Picture of Excel Sheet I need assistance with]

Thanks in advance for your time and assistance.

Comment: [`IF`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) should do the job

Comment: I cracked it - =IF(H42=0,0,SUM(H42:H43)) this seems to have worked